# Copy elements from one cell to another cell in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jquery, I'm trying to copy each "price" div after each "title" div.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 1</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$99.99</div></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 2</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$89.99</div></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 3</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$79.99</div></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

So it would look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 1</div><div class="price">$99.99</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$99.99</div></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 2</div><div class="price">$89.99</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$89.99</div></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="title">Item Title 3</div><div class="price">$79.99</div></td>
    <td><div class="price">$79.99</div></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

I've tried using the jquery script:

```
$(".price").each(function(){
    var newLink = $(this).clone();
    $(newLink).insertAfter('.title');
});
```

That doesn't work - it just takes every price and appends it to each title (so you end up with 3 prices per title, in other words).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Find your related title with $(this).closest('tr').find('.title')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(newLink).insertAfter('.title');
```

.title will find all elements with that class.  To get the related on to your price, you can do

```
$(newLink).insertAfter( $(this).closest('tr').find('.title') );
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice. Just as a clarification for anyone trying to use this later, the edited jquery would read:

`$(".price").each(function(){`
`var newLink = $(this).clone();`
`$(newLink).insertAfter( $(this).closest('tr').find('.title') );`
`});`